# IOS Swift How can fatal error unwrapping optional value

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4, avplayerviewcontroller

I have a ViewController called **BookViewC** all it does is display 1 video. The story board contains a IBOutlet called FullName and a UIView which I use to show the video . I have functionality that when you tap the video it is supposed to get the next video. **I always get the nil value for FullName when I get the next video**, it always gets the first video correctly .

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

on the IBOutLet for **fullname** which I understand why, is there a way around that ? Here is my code to clear things up

```
class BookViewC: UIViewController, VideoViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var VideoView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var FullName: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  // This method queries the database for the latest video
  ReloadTable(Offset: 0)

}

 func reloadTable(Offset: Int) {
 // Queries the database for video name
 // Returns data in Json
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    for Stream in Streams! {

                        if let fullname = Stream["fullname"] as? String            {
    // This below throws the nil error when getting the 2nd video
                            self.FullName.setTitle(fullname, for: .normal)

                        }
```

}

```
   // Method below simply shows the video
   self.PlayVideo(MediaHeight: Float(pic_height), MediaURL: s_image)
  }

func PlayVideo(MediaHeight: Float, MediaURL: String) {

    let movieURL = URL(string: MediaURL)

    videoCapHeight.constant = CGFloat(MediaHeight)
    streamsModel.playerView = AVPlayer(url: movieURL!)
    streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.player = streamsModel.playerView
    streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue
    streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = false
    streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.view.frame = VideoView.bounds
   VideoView.addSubview(streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.view)
    self.addChildViewController(streamsModel.MyAVPlayer)
    streamsModel.playerView?.isMuted = false
    streamsModel.MyAVPlayer.player?.play()
}
```

}

When you tap on a Video it goes to this class

```
class CustomAVPLayerC: AVPlayerViewController {


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


            // I try to return to my original Class now
            let BookC = BookViewC()
            for touch in touches {
                let location = touch.location(in: self.view)

                if location.x <  self.view.layer.frame.size.width / 2 {
                    print("Tapped Left")
                }
                else {
                    print("Tapped Right get next video")
                // Offset is now 1 which gets the 2nd video
                   BookC.ReloadTable(offset: 1)
                }
            }



    }


}
```

What  is happening is that Once I go to CustomAVPLayerC Controller all the IBOutlets from BookViewC become nil and then once I try to go back it gives me the error. Is there anything I can do to fix that or work around it ? The videos I display use the AVPlayer so on tap I must go to the CustomAVPLayerC Controller . Any suggestions would be great .

Comment: While returning to main class just remove the Subview you added instead of creating a new Instance of mainController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IBOutlets` are nil because your `BookVC` is not initialized from `.xib/storyboard`. Using delegation pattern should solve the issue. Following is an example that can help achieving this,

Create a protocol like below,

```
protocol CustomAVPLayerProtocol: class {
    func reloadTable(at index: Int)
}
```

Update `BookViewC` to conform to `CustomAVPLayerProtocol` like below,

```
extension BookViewC: CustomAVPLayerProtocol {

    func reloadTable(at index: Int) {
       self.reloadTable(Offset: index)
    }
}
```

then update `CustomAVPLayerC`

```
class CustomAVPLayerC: AVPlayerViewController {

   weak var delegate: CustomAVPLayerProtocol?

   func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self.view)

            if location.x <  self.view.layer.frame.size.width / 2 {
                print("Tapped Left")
            } else {
                let index = 1
                self.delegate?.reloadTable(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly in `BookViewC` set `CustomAVPLayerC`(when you are initializing) delegate like below,

```
let customAVPLayerVC = CustomAVPLayerC()
customAVPLayerVC.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines are probably causing your problem:

```
// I try to return to my original Class now
let BookC = BookViewC()
```

This is create a *new* copy of the BookViewC class, not getting you back to your original. When you then tell it to `reloadTable` it doesn't have any view behind it to work with.

The way to fix this is to ensure that your current BookViewC object (`this` in your first bit of code) is available for the video player to call the `reloadTable` method on. The normal way to do this is through a `delegate` pattern.